# VLookup match insert in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am new to this website; if I make any mistakes, please accept my apologies.

I am in need of some help regarding a search and replace method in Excel.

My goal is to select a range of random values from a column (e.g. column D) and see if there is a corresponding match for that value in the unique column (e.g. column A).
If this value is in column A, I would like to insert that value in the same row as the corresponding value column A but into another column (e.g. column E).

I have tired various different functions such as `IF`, `VLOOKUP`, and `MATCH` but have had no luck so far.

Can someone please show me how can this be done or if its even possible to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell E1, put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, D:D, 1, 0), "")
```

This looks for A1 in column D and if there is a match, put that matched value in the cell E1.

EDIT: I put the `IFERROR()` so that blanks are returned when there is no match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however will the value found in ColumnA, be inserted into Column E in the same row as in which it was originally in column A?

Comment: Yes it works, thank you so much Jerry. Just a another quick question in the cells where their is no value it shows #N/A , is it possible to have those cells blank instead?

Comment: @user2704941 Sure, wrap it with an IFERROR function like this: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, D:D, 1, 0), "")` I'll put it in my answer as well.