# Identify matching numbers and then imput a value from a different column

Tags: excel

I have two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 has a list of company names in column A, Revenue in column B and a unique number identifier in column D (also seen as "unique #forAAA in Sheet2). In Sheet2, I pulled a list from Hoovers, and the format comes up something like below (so this format should not be changed).

```
      Column A         B             C             D
    Company Name     Place     Type of Comp     Revenue
 1     AAA             US           HQ             10.0 M
 2  unique #forAAA
 3     BBB            India         Branch         5.0 M
 4  unique #forBBB
```

What I'd like to do is match the unique number for each company between Sheet1 and Sheet2 and then put the revenue # from Sheet2 into column B of Sheet1 which corresponds to the correct #. I'm pretty lost here, so any help or ideas would be great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm

Comment: You can also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18365821/1578604).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've tried the following =VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet2!A:A, 4,0) and it returns a N/A. The difference I think is that the # in Sheet2 is not in the same row as the Revenue.

Comment: Where is the unique identifier in Sheet2?

Comment: In ColumnA in rows 2,4. The unique identifier is placed underneath the company name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the unique identifier is on a different row than the result to be returned, you can use a variation using `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D, MATCH(D2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)-1)
```

`INDEX` will return the value within range `Sheet2!D:D` on row `MATCH(D2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)-1`.

`MATCH(D2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)` will give you the row number where the unique ID is found, then `-1` to get the row number of the revenue amount.

EDIT: As per comment, to remove the M, you can use this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(Sheet2!D:D, MATCH(D2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)-1),"M",""))
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks! Is there a way to get rid of the "M" at the end of each revenue?

Comment: @Steph Oh, okay xD Sure, you can use this around the index/match: `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(Sheet2!D:D, MATCH(D2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)-1),"M",""))`

Answer (score 0):

I would put the unique value in a column inserted before A (would be the new column A) instead of putting it below each row. Then, in the other sheet I'd put the VLOOKUP like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet2!A:E,5,0)
```

That should return the value in column E (column D before the column insertion, i.e. revenue for the unique company identifier).

Note that the third argument in the vlookup function is the number of the column you want to be retrieved, so the range defined in the second argument (Sheet2!A:E) should contain that column.